# Как сделать так, чтобы div'ы не залазили друг на друга?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/chelovechki/vsdnm/

Хочу, чтобы после того, как `sidebar2` не заходил на `content` при уменьшении окна браузера. Не могу додуматься, как сделать. Помогите!

Comment: пройдите по ссылке, измените размер экрана, думаю вы увидете что правый блок (sidebar2) залезает на картинку (content)

Comment: Хммм... А что же вы хотели? Картинка то ваша не масштабируется при изменении размеров видимой области экрана.

Comment: уже решил свою проблему поменяв значение min-width. я думаю те кто задает здесь вопросы хотят услышать ответы, а не критику в адрес того, что они чего-то не знают

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#logo_img {
 width:100%;   
}
```

Ну или фиксировать по ширине див, в зависимости от размеров картинки и.т.д, а вообще стоит смотреть сразу в сторону адаптивной верстки - [media](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media).

Comment: спасибо! а можно еще спросить вот что...хочется чтобы при уменьшении окна сайдбары уменьшались пропорционально а контент оставался нетронутым...самый простой пример это vk.com

Comment: если правильно вас понял, то просто фиксировать ширину divа  контента :) А вообще повторюсь http://htmlbook.ru/css/media, в поиске (на хабре, и пр) почитать про адаптивную верстку. В общем, ничего нового не сказал :)